# How to evaluate empty TextBox in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I have two column in my Excel Table (DataSource) and I am trying to evaluate both columns. Column 1 contains data and Column 2 is empty as shown below. The default `FormMode` is Edit, which contains 2 textboxes titled as "Column 1" and "Column 2", with 1 button to see the collection (See Below Code). Before using If condition I wanted to check whether I can see my record for row 1. The dafault property for Column1 is set to `Gallery2.Selected.Column1` and the default property for Column 2 is set to `" "`. I used below code to see whether the collection will return my record,unfortunately instead of returning my record I saw Empty table with my column names i.e Column1 and Column2 under View -> Collections. Not sure what is wrong with below code. The code should return expected output in View> Collections.

Any help is appreciated!

**Data Source**

[image]

**Code:**

```
ClearCollect(Test,LookUp(Table1,Column1=DataCardValue6.Text && Column2= " ")
```

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Updated Code:**

```
ClearCollect(Test,LookUp(Table1,Column1=DataCardValue6.Text && Column2= IsBlank(Trim(Column2Name))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsBlank` and `Trim` to check for any empty or whitespace strings.

```
IsBlank(Trim(Column2))
```

Trim will remove any whitespace and IsBlank will return a true/false if the string is empty or not after the trim.

[IsBlank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-isblank-isempty)

[Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-isblank-isempty)

UPDATE: Check only for IsBlank where Column2 is evaluated, the way you wrote it it's checking if `Column2 = bool` which will have a type mismatch since it's checking a string vs a bool, change to this:

```
ClearCollect(Test,LookUp(Table1,Column1=DataCardValue6.Text && IsBlank(Trim(Column2))))
```

Comment: Getting "Incompatible type. We Can't evaluate your formula because the value being compared in the formula aren't same type" warning. See above updated code. Thanks!

Comment: is the goal to have `LookUp` pull from the table only where `Column2` is empty?

Comment: The goal is to pull the record from Column1 let's say UID1 and also empty row from Column 2. This way I can use IF condition to update Column2 . if there exist a record for UID1 then column2 will be updated. Once update is done, then additional row will be appended for same UID1 in Column 2.

Comment: @biggboss2019 Updated the answer

Comment: Does it have to be "Column2 inside Trim ? IsBlank(Trim(Column2)). Since my DataSource is Excel Table I used DataCardValue.Text and that seemed to have worked.  Just wanted to double check. If I used Column2 as my Column Name then it is returning me empty table. As mentioned in my post.

Comment: @biggboss2019 please edit the question and show what is the expected output

Comment: @biggboss2019 have you tried changing the condition to test if it's the DataCardValue6 issue? try `Column1="UID1"`